# Automatic nested mocking with DefaultValue.Mock not working as expected

Tags: unit-testing, moq

Moq claims that it can automatically mock recursive or nested objects https://github.com/Moq/moq4/wiki/Quickstart#customizing-mock-behavior however I am having trouble getting this to actually work.

I copied an existing test directly from Moq's own test suite and it fails for me but I cannot figure out why.

Here is the verbatim test I copied from Moq (original source: https://github.com/Moq/moq4/blob/8bc9b111640203af3995fbac98160a5d1f9e1ae2/UnitTests/MockBehaviorFixture.cs#L124)

```
[Fact]
public void ReturnsMockDefaultValueForLooseBehaviorOnAbstract()
{
    var mock = new Mock<Foo>(MockBehavior.Loose) { DefaultValue = DefaultValue.Mock };

    var value = mock.Object.Bar;

    Assert.True(value is IMocked);

    value = mock.Object.GetBar();

    Assert.True(value is IMocked);
}
```

And here is my definition of `Foo` which I created in the same file as the test:

```
public class Foo
{
    public List<string> Bar { get; set; }
    public List<string> GetBar()
    {
        return new List<string>();
    }
}
```

Everything I can find on Moq's site leads me to think this should work but the above `Assert.True` calls fail.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the example that you have given your property and method are not virtual so Moq cannot override them with any behavior. In the example in the link, the property and method are both abstract and as such Moq can and does override the behavior.

Add the virtual modifier to both the method and the property to make the test pass:

```
public class Foo
{
    public virtual List<string> Bar { get; set; }
    public virtual List<string> GetBar()
    {
        return new List<string>();
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks! I've been away from C# for too long and used to Java's override behavior.